# I have a responsive HTML email, where I want on a mobile device hide that button and show a different button

Tags: html, mobile

I have a responsive HTML page, with buttons to go to an optin and an optout page. For mobile I want to hide that button and show two other buttons instead. I'm not looking at specific mobile phones but rather to screensize:

/* Media Query for mobile */

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {  

    /* This resizes tables and images to be 100% wide with a proportionate width */
    table[class=emailwrapto100pc], img[class=emailwrapto100pc]{width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}

    /* Hide stuff on mobiles */
    table[class=emailnomob],td[class=emailnomob],img[class=emailnomob],span[class=emailnomob]{display:none !important;}
```

I use it to hide the tabs on the bottom of the page and show the links as large buttons instead. But instead of just reformatting the link, I want to use an different link altogether.

(since typing on a mobile is a drag, I want to use a filled out mailto: instead, so the person doesn't have to type anything).

Comment: That is the worst title you can imagine for a question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my face...
I had the two classes already defined.

```
    <class="emailmobbutton">
```

to make the link into a big button and

```
    <class="emailnomob">
```

*This was my code for the buttons:*

```
    <td align="center" style="padding-bottom:20px;"><a href="#" class="emailmobbutton">
Our Website</a><span class="emailnomob"> | </span>
```

And this is what I changed:

```
    <span class="emailnomob"><a href="#">Join now</a></span>
    <span class="emailnomob"> | </span>
    <span class="emailmobbutton"><a href="#">Send mail</a>
```

Works like a charm. Can use mailto: as link now.

Comment: additional info: it almost works... in mobile it works great, but now the new link also shows on PC. Have to find a way around that.

Comment: Now it works: 
I made an additional 

        @media query screen and (min-width:1024px)

Then I added a class: emailnopc with display:none
The last class in the previous answer I changed to:

        <span class="emailnopc"><a href="#" class="emailmobbutton"> Send mail</a>